# Browsers keeps sending NTLM token instead of Kerberos - How to solve it?

Tags: java, active-directory, jetty, kerberos, spnego

I can't seem to correctly configure the system and have the browser send a [kerberos](/questions/tagged/kerberos) ticket to the web-server. Instead, a `NTLM` token is sent.

**Q:** How can I solve this?

All details and configurations are listed below.

---

**Infrastructure:**

I have three machines within the domain `COMPANY.local`:

- `PC-I7.COMPANY.local` (on `192.168.0.5`). It acts as `KDC`, it's an `Active-Directory` server with the other machines (see below) registered in the AD. Also has the `DNS` for the local network configured. The domain in the Active Directory is: `COMPANY.local`
- `SOFTWARE.COMPANY.local` (on `192.168.0.10`) runs the [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty) web-application which has the `Jetty/SPNego` support configured.
- `OTHER.COMPANY.local` (on `192.168.0.9`), just a client so I can access the software server from another machine.

The last two are actually `VM`s running on a `linux` server in the intranet. They are reachable with their own IP. Their primary `DNS` in `Network Configuration` points to `192.168.0.5`.

Both are joined in `COMPANY.local` and are present as computers in the `AD`.

I know client and server [should stay on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410254/8524301); and being them onto two different `VM`'s should avoid this issue.

All three machines are registered as `A` hosts in the `DNS` with a reverse pointer for each of them in the `Reverse lookup zone`.

---

**SPN**

After having created the user `software` in the Active Directory, I generate the keytab file

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL -mapuser software@COMPANY.LOCAL -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass __PassForADUserSoftware__ -out C:/winnt/krb5.keytab
```

I get the following output which seems to contain an error:

```
Targeting domain controller: PC-I7.COMPANY.local
  Failed to set property 'userPrincipalName' to 'HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL' on Dn 'CN=Software SSO Kerberized WebServer,DC=COMPANY,DC=local': 0x13.
  WARNING: Failed to set UPN HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL on CN=Software SSO Kerberized WebServer,DC=COMPANY,DC=local.
  kinits to 'HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL' will fail.
Successfully mapped HTTP/software.company.local to software.
Password successfully set!
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Output keytab to C:/winnt/krb5.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502 
keysize 64 HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 8 etype 0x1 (DES-CBC-CRC) keylength 8 (0x0bf1688040abadba)
keysize 64 HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 8 etype 0x3 (DES-CBC-MD5) keylength 8 (0x0bf1688040abadba)
keysize 72 HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 8 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC) keylength 16 (0x737d9811dd38e108741461ba79153192)
keysize 88 HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 8 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) keylength 32 (0xcc8ab2939f822f9df6904a987954e0cfaa261bc36803af6c5f8d9a98f1d4f2aa)
keysize 72 HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 8 etype 0x11 (AES128-SHA1) keylength 16 (0xd616b814dcd1b955f125ab4de5895d39)
```

The `AD` user has the two `This account supports the Kerbers AES-...` checkboxes checked.

---

**The `OTHER.COMPANY.local` server**

I login to this machine via `RDP` with the credentials:

```
user: Administrator
pass: ARandomPass
```

When asking for a ticket from `OTHER` server with

```
kinit HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL
```

I can see this packets with `wireshark`

[image: Packet traffic from browser server to KDC]

Internet explorer (and therefore Chrome) have the following settings in `Internet Options`:

```
Security > Local Intranet > Sites > *.company.local
Security > Custom level > Automatic logon only in Intranet area
```

When I reach the web application on `http://software.company.local:8998/software/login`

I can see the browser sends a `NTLM` request

[image: Wireshark: Browser sends a NTLM request]

and I can see the [Defective Token exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297772/8524301) on the server side

```
WARN:oejs.SpnegoLoginService:qtp506835709-28: 
GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:306)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService.login(SpnegoLoginService.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticator.validateRequest(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also this info appears in the `java` log:

```
Debug is true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false 
ticketCache is null isInitiator false 
KeyTab is C:/software/inst/modules/common-config/auth/krb5.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false 
principal is HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL tryFirstPass is false 
useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
```

Information I can gather from the linked answer:

- Point 1: The SPN for the HTTP service does match the URL entered by the browser. I input `software.company.local` in the browser which is the same as the SPN `HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL`
- Point 2: `*.company.local` is added to the trusted sites.
- Point 3: I'm not restricting the encrpytion to `DES-CBC-MD5`
- Point 3: I have checked `AES-128` and `AES-256` ... but not `DES` because the Windows Server version I am working with has the checkbox saying `Use only Kerberos DES encryption types for this account`, which is not what I want. Should I check it?

---

**The `SOFTWARE.COMPANY.local` server**

The [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty) web-application is registered as a Windows Server.

These are the configuration files:

`krb5.ini` file:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = COMPANY.LOCAL
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes128-cts,aes256-cts,arcfour-hmac-md5,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96    
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes128-cts,aes256-cts,arcfour-hmac-md5,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes128-cts,aes256-cts,arcfour-hmac-md5,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_keytab_name = FILE:C:/software/inst/modules/common-config/krb5.keytab

[domain_realm]
COMPANY.local = COMPANY.LOCAL
.company.local = COMPANY.LOCAL

[realms]
COMPANY.LOCAL = {
    admin_server = PC-I7.COMPANY.local
    kdc = PC-I7.COMPANY.local:88
}
```

`spnego.conf` file:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    principal = "HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL"
    keyTab = "C:/software/inst/modules/common-config/auth/krb5.keytab"
    useKeyTab = true
    storeKey = true
    debug = true
    isInitiator = false;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    principal = "HTTP/software.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL"
    useKeyTab = true
    keyTab = "C:/software/inst/modules/common-config/auth/krb5.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    debug=true
    isInitiator=false;
};
```

and this is the `spnego.properties` file:

```
targetName = HTTP/software.company.local
```

My `jetty-web.xml` configuration file contains:

```
<Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Company Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config">
                <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/modules/common-config/auth/spnego.properties</Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
    <Set name="checkWelcomeFiles">true</Set>
</Get>
```

This is how I programmatically register the `spnego` configuration in `Java`:

```
private SecurityHandler wrapEnableSSOAuthHandlers(final Handler collection) {

    // ini file
    System.setProperty(
            "java.security.krb5.conf",
            _config.getString("authentication.win_sso.spnego.krb5") // the krb5.ini file
    );
    System.setProperty(
            "java.security.auth.login.config",
            _config.getString("authentication.win_sso.spnego.login") // the spnego.conf file
    );
    System.setProperty(
            "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly",
            "false"
    );

    final Constraint spnegoConstraint = new Constraint();
    spnegoConstraint.setName(Constraint.__SPNEGO_AUTH);

    final String domainRealm = _config.getString("authentication.win_sso.domain.realm");    // resolves to COMPANY.LOCAL

    spnegoConstraint.setRoles(new String[]{domainRealm});
    spnegoConstraint.setAuthenticate(true);

    final ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    mapping.setConstraint(spnegoConstraint);
    mapping.setPathSpec("/*");

    final String spnegoProperties = _config.getString("authentication.win_sso.spnego.properties");      // the spnego.properties file

    final SpnegoLoginService loginService = new SpnegoLoginService();
    loginService.setConfig(spnegoProperties);
    loginService.setName(domainRealm);

    final ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
    securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
    securityHandler.setConstraintMappings(new ConstraintMapping[]{mapping});
    securityHandler.setRealmName(domainRealm);
    securityHandler.setAuthenticator(new SpnegoAuthenticator());
    securityHandler.setHandler(collection);
    return securityHandler;
}
```

and

```
// here I disable the TRACE method for all calls 
Handler wrappedSecurityHandler = wrapDisableTraceHandlers(handlers);
wrappedSecurityHandler = wrapEnableSSOAuthHandlers(wrappedSecurityHandler);
_server.setHandler(wrappedSecurityHandler);
```

---

**EDIT 1: Additional info**

I have downloaded the [Kerberos Authentication Tester Tool](http://blog.michelbarneveld.nl/michel/archive/2009/12/05/kerberos-authentication-tester.aspx) and when running it from the `KDC` server (`192.168.0.5`) and testing against `http://software.company.local:8998` it shows a correct `Kerberos` authentication.

When running it from the `192.168.0.10` server (where the browser is) it says:

> Unexpected authorization header

and authentication method: `NTLM`.

I guess it's either a `DNS` issue or the fact that they are two `VM` on the same server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, having client and server on two distinct virtual machines ( that are **on the same** physical server! ) can lead to a `NTLM` token.

I thought `VM`'s would dodge the [client-and-server-on-the-same-machine-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410254/8524301).

So, if you

- like me, are testing with `VM`'s residing on the same physical machine, and
- have set everything right but still getting a `Defective token detected`,

you should try to access the `server` from a different computer (as long as that machine is joined to the company domain).

Comment: Hi Marko, I am having the same problem, whilst developing a custom access management solution based on CAS, Kerberos and AD. In fact, i am running Kerberos in a Linux machine, but CAS is running on my local tomcat. I see that CAS always falls into NTML authentication and indeed the token I receive always contains NTML mechanisms identification. So, apparently, there is no way to perform this unless CAS running on a different machine. I'm going to test this scenario and let you know.