# 401 SPNEGO SSO with Linux client

Tags: java, linux, spring, kerberos, spnego

I can't manage to configure my Ubuntu VM to single sign-on on my Spring Security web application under Spnego. Did I do anything wrong or am I missing something?

I already got to SSO on a Windows 7 VM, so I believe it's Linux specific.

My configuration is detailed below.

---

**Infra**

I have four machines that run in two different hardware:

1. `WIN-SRV2008.company.local`: the VM KDC running Windows Server 2008 (**hardware A**)
2. `TOMCAT.company.local`: running the `Tomcat 7` web application (**hardware A**)
3. `W7-CLIENT.company.local`: VM Windows 7 client which SSO **works** (**hardware B**)
4. `U-CLIENT.company.local`: VM Ubuntu 17.10.1 client which SSO **doesn't work** (**hardware B**)

---

**SPN**

My SPN, `krb5.ini` and `login.conf` were based on [this thread's description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082273/browsers-keeps-sending-ntlm-token-instead-of-kerberos-how-to-solve-it).

---

**Spnego**

I basically followed [Spring Security Kerberos - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/html/ssk-spnego.html), except removing form login, resulting on:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${kerberos.service-principal}")
    private String servicePrincipal;

    @Value("${kerberos.keytab-location}")
    private String keytabLocation;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList(new RoleVoter(),new WebExpressionVoter()));
        http
            .authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(affirmativeBased)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
                    spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
            .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        return new SpnegoEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider() {
        LoginKerberosAuthentication provider = new LoginKerberosAuthentication();
        SunJaasKerberosClient client = new SunJaasKerberosClient();
        client.setDebug(true);
        provider.setKerberosClient(client);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(usuarioDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(usuarioDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        ticketValidator.setServicePrincipal(servicePrincipal);
        ticketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(new FileSystemResource(keytabLocation));
        ticketValidator.setDebug(true);
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public UsuarioDetailsService usuarioDetailsService() {
        return new UsuarioDetailsService();
    }
```

---

**Ubuntu client**

To join the domain I followed the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install realmd krb5-user software-properties-common python-software-properties packagekit

sudo realm join COMPANY.local -U 'administrator@COMPANY.LOCAL' -v
```

Until I got to generate kerberos ticket with:

```
kinit my_ubuntu_user@COMPANY.local
```

I actually checked cache with `klist`, that outputed:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: my_ubuntu_user@COMPANY.local

Valid starting        Expires                Service principal
30/10/2018 17:25:47   31/10/2018 03:25:47    krbtgt/COMPANY.local@COMPANY.local
            renew until 31/10/2018 17:25:43
```

And lastly, I authenticated successfully using:

```
sudo su my_ubuntu_user@COMPANY.local
```

---

**SSO - the problem**

When I try to access my application homepage using Firefox (with trusted sites config) just as I do with the Windows 7 client, I only get [the 401 Negotiate header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSgmZ.png) and no response token is sent.
Meaning that, when I input an actual url to `SpnegoEntryPoint` constructor, I get redirected to this fallback.

---

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you doing with that `su <kerberos principal>` ?!?!? The Kerberos ticket cache is available only to the Linux user that ran the `kinit` command... If you `su` after that, you switch to another cache (presumably empty)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter You were correct and it worked!! Thank you so much. I had followed blindly a Linux AD configuring tutorial and tought `su` was ok for testing the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Samson's comment I was able to make it work.

I was indeed switching to an empty cache by doing `sudo su my_ubuntu_user@COMPANY.local`, what made my application login respond 401.